# Wirless disabled by hardware switch on a Toshiba Notebook Model: NB205-N311/W

Tags: wireless

I've got a Toshiba Notebook Model: NB205-N311/W
it has no external Wireless hardware switch. It can only be switched on when pressing on FN+F8 (on Windows XP) When I tried doing the same thing on Ubuntu 11.10 it didn't work.

I need help in switching it on. My wireless wont work until I switch it on ??? Please!!

Comment: Hi All ... I keep checking on my posted question, trying to see if anyone had answered it? Please can anyone help me with it ... sorry for the trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if it is enabled in bios.  Even if it is, reset bios to deafault settings to make sure.  Then unplug, take battery out amd hold the power button for 30 seconds.  It should work then, at least it did for me for the same problem.

Comment: cwwk thanks for the reply... I tried doing as you advised but it didin't work. The BIOS was able to turn the wireless switch on and off for me. I made sure to turn it on from the BIOS then saved and exited and then turned off the NoteBook and took out the batteries but when I turned it on again the Wireless Light Indicator was on and Ubuntu was still telling me that its switched off.... Why is Abuntu insisting that its off while its on??  ............... your post made me know how to turn my wirless on and off ... Thanks .. but it didn't solve my problem :( I still need help ??

Comment: By the way just to be clear I did restore the BIOS to Defaults and saved it too... Default turns on the Wireless switch!